# How to calculate score based on userform combobox responses dynamically

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with 7 comboboxes that have the option of `Yes`, `No`, `Partially` and `N/A`. Based on the response in each of the box I have a textbox that populates the overall score.

`Yes = 1`,
`Partially = 0.5`,
`No = 0` and
`NA = 0`.

I have the code that calculates based on the combobox responses and if I simply divide by the total boxes (7) it calculates however not all forms will have 7 responses (NA is an option but is then basically doesn't count for or against them). So I need to figure out how to divide the total score by the total responses. I'm sure it is super easy but I am not struggling to figure it out.

This is the code I current have in there that does not give me the correct %

```
TXTScore = Format((nYes + nPartial * 0.5) / nYes + nPartial + nNo, "Percent")
```

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim c As Control, nYes As Long, nPartial As Long, nNo As Long


For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
        If c.Value = "Yes" Then nYes = nYes + 1
        If c.Value = "Partially" Then nPartial = nPartial + 1
        If c.Value = "No" Then nNo = nNo + 1
    End If
Next c

TXTScore = Format((nYes + nPartial * 0.5) / nYes + nPartial + nNo, "Percent")
End Sub
```

For example - 6 Yes response and 1 NA would = 100%, 5 Yes responses, 1 Partially and 1 NA would equal 92%

Comment: Actually that is a math question. Note that `(nYes + nPartial * 0.5) / nYes + nPartial + nNo` is the same as `((nYes + nPartial * 0.5) / nYes) + nPartial + nNo` but you probably meant to use `(nYes + nPartial * 0.5) / (nYes + nPartial + nNo)` • Use brackets the correct way. Multiplication and division are always calculated befor addition and subtraction: [Order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should count NA also (and add some brackets, I think)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim c As Control, nYes As Long, nPartial As Long, nNo As Long, nNA As Long
nYes = 0
nPartial = 0
nNo = 0
nNA = 0


For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
        If c.Value = "Yes" Then nYes = nYes + 1
        If c.Value = "Partially" Then nPartial = nPartial + 1
        If c.Value = "No" Then nNo = nNo + 1
        If c.Value = "NA" Then nNA = nNA + 1
    End If
Next c

TXTScore = Format((nYes + nPartial * 0.5) / (nYes + nPartial + nNo + nNA), "Percent")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Van for your quick response! I put that in and the score I get is 310.00%...im missing something...

Comment: @VanNg these local variables are `0` after `Dim` no need to initialize them.

Comment: Amazing! That is exactly what I needed. Thank you Van and Peh. That fixed my issues!

Comment: Yes, they are. I mentioned if they could be oversummed something elsewhere

Comment: @VanNg no they cannot, they are declared locally in `Sub CommandButton1_Click` no other sub can see or change them.

Comment: Hmm... Or may be there multivalue controls?

Comment: @VanNg No, initializing them where you did cannot have any effect at all. That's impossible. Probably he had a copy/paste error the first time.

Comment: Yep. Peh, and how it was done - I think JBeets just missed something at first check

Comment: @VanNg Probably he just jumped in before you edited and added the brackets.